# Why did Neil say "Doesn't matter"?

Tags: tenet

Context: Grandfather Paradox:

> Neil: But in the future, those in power clearly believe that you can
> kick grandpa down the stairs, gouge his eyes out, slit his throat,
> without consequence.
>
> Protagonist: Could they be right?
>
> Neil: **Doesn't matter**.

Why did Neil say "Doesn't matter"?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [the script](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/tenet-2020.pdf), the lines are a little different.

> **NEIL**
> Bringing us to the grandfather
> paradox.
>
> **PROTAGONIST**
> The what?
>
> **NEIL**
> The classic thought experiment – if
> you went back in time and killed
> your own grandfather, how could you
> have been born to commit the act?
>
> **PROTAGONIST**
> What’s the answer?
>
> **NEIL**
> There is no answer, it’s a paradox.
> But in the future, those in power
> clearly believe that you can kick
> Grandpa down the stairs, gouge his
> eyes and slit his throat without
> consequence.
>
> **PROTAGONIST**
> Could they be right?
>
> **NEIL**
> It doesn’t matter. They believe it,
> so they’re willing to destroy us.
> Can I go back to sleep?

So the context for his comment is that those in power don't believe that killing Neil and Protagonist would threaten their existence (since they don't believe in the grandfather paradox), so they're willing to do it, whether or not their belief is true that the past cannot affect the future.

Or, to quote [this review](https://www.vulture.com/2020/09/tenet-explained-whats-going-on-in-the-plot-of-this-movie.html):

> .... They talk about time travel and the grandfather paradox — if they’re trying to stop the future from killing them in the past, doesn’t the fact that they still exist mean they succeeded? They resolve not to think about it too much.